# MVC View, adding dynamically html code to divs

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi I have a View with two columns (divs) and I would like to add to those columns some divs with charts. I don't know how many of those charts I will have and to which column they should go until it is running.

Is it possible to add alternately to columns depending on some conditions?

```
<div class="column column-small">
      @foreach (String c in Model.getSettings().chartsList)
      {

          <div class="drag-box white-box chart-box" onmouseup="refreshAfterDrop()">
               <div class="handle"><div class="close"></div></div>
               @Html.Action(c, "Report")
          </div>
      }
</div> 
<div class="column column-big">
</div>
```

At the moment this code works and is adding every chart to first column (#column-small)
How can I edit this code to add for example every second chart to first column and rest to second column?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this (I haven't tested it):

```
@{
  var list = Model.getSettings().chartsList;
}
<div class="column column-small">
      @for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i += 2)
      {
          <div class="drag-box white-box chart-box" onmouseup="refreshAfterDrop()">
             <div class="handle"><div class="close"></div></div>
             @Html.Action(list[i], "Report")
          </div>
      }
</div> 
<div class="column column-big">
      @for(int i = 1; i < list.Count; i += 2)
      {
          <div class="drag-box white-box chart-box" onmouseup="refreshAfterDrop()">
             <div class="handle"><div class="close"></div></div>
             @Html.Action(list[i], "Report")
          </div>
      }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an example! Something like this might work.

```
var i = 0;
@foreach (String c in Model.getSettings().chartsList)
{
  <div class="column column-small">
  @if(i%2 == 0){
     <div class="drag-box white-box chart-box" onmouseup="refreshAfterDrop()">
     <div class="handle"><div class="close"></div></div>
       @Html.Action(c, "Report")
     </div>
  }
  </div> 
  <div class="column column-big">
  @if(i%2 != 0)
  {
       //Add the other charts here.
  }
  </div>
  i++;
}
```

You need to take care of the syntax.

Comment: Id doesn't add it to the same column, it creates new columns under the current ones.

Comment: You need to handle the columns in the CSS. I thought your CSS is already defined and working
This code will make sure that the charts are divided into different divs.

Comment: Yes my CSS is defined and working. What I mean is that your code does't add chart divs to existing columns but it creates new columns for every two chart divs. so after running the code I have: <div class="column column-small"><chart></div><div class="column column-big"><chart></div><div class="column column-small"><chart></div><div class="column column-big"><chart><div/>

Comment: I tried your edited code but it still not adding to the same column.

Comment: Same thing. If I have 4 charts it creates 8 columns (4 column-big and 4 column-small). I would like to have only 2 columns with 2 charts in each of them.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Adding data in two columns]

Here is an example snapshot, where I added sample data to divs.
and following is the sample Razor view code

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    List<string> testList = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        testList.Add("Item" + i + "in div");
    }
    var cnt = 0;
}

<style>
    .column
    {
        width: 400px;
    }
    .column-left
    {
        float: left;
    }
    .column-right
    {
        float: right;
    }
</style>
    @foreach (var t in testList)
    {

        <div class="column column-left">
            @if (cnt % 2 == 0)
            {
                <div>
                    @t
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="column column-right">
            @if (cnt % 2 != 0)
            {
                <div>
                    @t
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: I think you didn't understood what I'm trying to achieve. Your code align divs left and right which is very good, but I'm trying to put them to the same column div. This is because I'm doing drag and drop charts so user can drag charts between two columns. If I use your code I'm getting 5 left columns stacked on top of each other and the same 5 on right hand side. It's probably me didn't explain you properly what I'm trying to achieve. Many thanks for your help, it is much appreciated.

Comment: You got the answer that's important :)